# Dependency issue (gir 1.2) cannot install VLC (Problematic PPA)

Tags: apt, upgrade, package-management, updates, dpkg

Just after a regular update done by the software updater, I received an error, after which I am unable to manually upgrade software and Ubuntu.

When I run

```
sudo apt upgrade
[sudo] password for gaj: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gir1.2-peas-1.0 : Depends: libpeas-1.0-0 (>= 1.18.0) but 1.16.0-1ubuntu2 is installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
```

Running `sudo-apt -f install` returns:

```
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libpeas-1.0-0
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 5 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/197 kB of archives.
After this operation, 43,0 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 297813 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libpeas-1.0-0_1.18.0-2~ubuntu16.04.1~ppa1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libpeas-1.0-0 (1.18.0-2~ubuntu16.04.1~ppa1) over (1.16.0-1ubuntu2) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libpeas-1.0-0_1.18.0-2~ubuntu16.04.1~ppa1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/libpeas-1.0/loaders/libpython3loader.so', which is also in package libpeas-1.0-0-python3loader 1.16.0-1ubuntu2
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu3) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libpeas-1.0-0_1.18.0-2~ubuntu16.04.1~ppa1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Now, I've tried these:

```
sudo dpkg -- configure -a
sudo apt-get install -f
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get upgrade -f
```

Nothing seems to work. How can I fix the dependencies? It seems to be a relevant file, I wasn't installing any software.

I discovered that I had a **problematic PPA**, which I could disable and there were no problems.

**PPA: **http://ppa.launchpad.net/nicola-onorata/desktop/ubuntu****

However, if I disable it, I cannot install VLC, for example. I receive the following dependecies missing:

```
vlc : Depends: libgles1-mesa (>= 7.8.1) but it is not going to be installed or
                libgles1
```

Any advice?
Thank you.

Comment: After you remove that ppa could run these and post the outputs: `apt-get -s -o Debug::pkgProblemResolver=yes install vlc` , `echo q | aptitude -s install vlc` , `sudo apt-get install -y apt-rdepends; apt-cache policy $(apt-rdepends vlc 2>/dev/null | grep "^[a-zA-Z]" | sort | paste -s -d" ")`

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following, **but be warned, there is a chance you can break your system**:

```
sudo dpkg --purge --pending
sudo apt-get install -f
```

Comment: I won't do it if it can break my sytem.

Comment: @Mookey It simply removes any pending half-complete installs. It should be okay in your case as there isn't anything critical in the listed unmet dependencies.

Comment: The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 vlc : Depends: libgles1-mesa (>= 7.8.1) but it is not going to be installed or
                libgles1